# in php project, bootstrap in ajax doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to show bootstrap modal message using ajax in php. I can get alert message under ajax but not modal. When I use ajax inside javascript. It worked but with same structure, it is not working now. I think it has to do with submit button. I set type for button tag to submit for html 5 validation. but it doesn't cooperate well with bootstrap modal. When I change type to button modal works but html5 does't work. Is there any way to resolve this issue? I have spent so many hours now but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in adavanced.

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){

  if($("form")[0].checkValidity()) {

      var params = jQuery("#frm").serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
      url:'join_process.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:params,
      dataType:"text",
      error:function(){
          alert('join fails!');
      },
      success:function(data){
          if(data==true){
              alert("test");

             $('.modal-body').html("<center>member join success</center>");
            // Display Modal
            $('#empModal').modal('show'); 
              // Add response in Modal body


        }else{
             $('.modal-body1').html(data);
         // Display Modal
        $('#empModal1').modal('show'); 

        }
      }
  });
  }else{ console.log("invalid form");}

 });
 });



 </script>



 </head>

 <body>
 <?php
  headerNav();
 ?>
 <!-- Page Content -->
 <div class="container">



 <div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-3">
      <?php
       sideMenu();


    ?>


  </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-3 -->

  <div class="col-lg-9 text-center mt-1">
  <?php
   // $bookinfo=  get_book_info($new);

     ?>
            <br/>


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
         <div class="col-lg-6">
             <table class="table table-bordered text-center" id="test">


                <form id="frm">
                      <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" bgcolor="#d2e6f7">Membership</th>  
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="name">name:</label></td>
                            <td style="text-align:left;"><input type="text" 
    id="name" name="name" value="" maxlength="20" size="20" required/></tr>

                      <tr>
                          <td><label for="id">id:</label></td>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><input type="text" 
       id="id" name="id" value="" maxlength="20" size="20" required/>
                          <div id="id_chk"></div>       
                      </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="pass">password:</label></td>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><input type="password" 
         id="pass" name="pass" maxlength="20" size="20" required/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <td><label for="pass_confirm">password confirm:</label></td>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><input type="password" 
         id="pass_confrm" name="pass_confrm" maxlength="20" size="20" required/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="email">email:</label></td>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><input type="email" 
       id="email" name="email" value="" maxlength="20" size="20" required/></tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td><label for="addr">address:</label></td>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><input type="text" 
         id="addr" name="addr" value="" maxlength="20" size="20" required/></tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td><label for="cellphone">cellphone:</label></td>
                        <td style="text-align:left;">

                            <input type="tel" id="cellphone" name="cellphone" 
        placeholder="01091112333" required>
                        </td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                        <td>Want to be administrator:</td>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><input type="radio" 
         name="isadmin" value="Y">
                <label for="y">Yes</label>


                <input type="radio" name="isadmin" value="N" checked>
                <label for="n">No</label>

                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                        <td colspan='2'>

                            <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn- 
       primary">가입</button> 

                        </td>
                        </tr>
                </form>


            </table>


           <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="empModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
     id="close">&times;</button>
     </div>
    <div class="modal-body1">

     </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
       dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


    <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="empModal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="close" 
    onclick="location.href='index.php'">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" 
    onclick="location.href='index.php'">Close</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      </div>





      </div>
             <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
     </div>
     </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```